# Enable TypeScript auto import in WebStorm

Tags: angular, webstorm

I'm watching that course on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvD2Dvzj8_E&list=PL55RiY5tL51rLeDxRPlE6Hsnss3QDCCKc) and when he writes for example `Http` WebStorm automatically adds it's desired import. How can I add that feature?

I have these options in settings

[image]

Comment: from your screenshot I can see that it's already enabled. what WebStorm version do you use?

Comment: @lena it's latest. it seems restart of ide helped